# How to automatically re-calculate the y axis scale after limiting the x axis in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to plot some spectrographic data from a large list of data frames. I want to restrict the graph to just wavelengths between 400 and 900 nm. I know how to set the x-axis limits using scale_x_continuous() or xlim(). The problem is that after I have done this, the y-axis does not automatically readjust to the min/max values displayed. I don't want to set it manually, as each data frame processed by my loop will have a different range.

Where `summary` is my list of data frames, then this code gives me a list of plots, without the axes adjusted:

```
plotlist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(summary)){
  plotlist[[length(plotlist)+1]] <- ggplot(summary[[i]], aes(Wavelength, average)) +
    geom_line(aes(color=Sample)) +
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=average-sem, ymax=average+sem, color=Sample), alpha=0.5) +
    ylab("Absorbance (AU)") + ggtitle(names(summary)[i]) +
    theme_classic()
}
plotlist[[33]]
```

This gives me:
[Plot without axis adjustment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Wn4.png)

If I adjust the x-axis to 400 - 900 like this:

```
plotlist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(summary)){
  plotlist[[length(plotlist)+1]] <- ggplot(summary[[i]], aes(Wavelength, average)) +
    scale_x_continuous(name="Wavelength (nm)", limits=c(400, 900), expand=c(0,0)) +
    geom_line(aes(color=Sample), na.rm=TRUE) +
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=average-sem, ymax=average+sem, color=Sample), alpha=0.5, na.rm=TRUE) +
    ylab("Absorbance (AU)") + ggtitle(names(summary)[i]) +
    theme_classic()
}
plotlist[[33]]
```

Then I get this plot, with the x-axis correct, but the scale of the y-axis is now too large for the displayed data:
[Plot with correct x-axis, but wrong y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4x2t.png)

How do I automatically adjust the y-axis to the appropriate min/max but only in the 400-900 nm range of the x-axis?

Comment: EDIT: I have tried changing the order in which I add the scales, geoms etc, but this makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. However, since I don't have access to your data, I wasn't able to test whether it actually works.

You could define the max average value for the range of wavelengths prior to building your plot and then call that value in a ylim function.

The two lines I added are:

```
 y_scale <- max(summary[[i]]$average[summary[[i]]$Wavelength >= 400 & summary[[i]]$Wavelength <= 900])
```

and,

```
ylim(0, (y_scale + 0.5))+
```

The final code then looks like this:

```
plotlist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(summary)){
  y_scale <- max(summary[[i]]$average[summary[[i]]$Wavelength >= 400 &   summary[[i]]$Wavelength <= 900])
  plotlist[[length(plotlist)+1]] <- ggplot(summary[[i]], aes(Wavelength, average)) +
    scale_x_continuous(name="Wavelength (nm)", limits=c(400, 900), expand=c(0,0)) +
    ylim(0, (y_scale + 0.5))+
    geom_line(aes(color=Sample), na.rm=TRUE) +
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=average-sem, ymax=average+sem, color=Sample), alpha=0.5, na.rm=TRUE) +
    ylab("Absorbance (AU)") + ggtitle(names(summary)[i]) +
    theme_classic()
}
plotlist[[33]]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In addition to this, there is a ggplot extension that deals with plotting spectra. I have never used it so I can't speak to how i would help with this problem, but it might be worth looking into. https://bitbucket.org/aphalo/ggspectra

Comment: Many thanks tbradley, that's a nice solution, but I get a "Error in summary[[i]]$average[summary[[i]]] : invalid subscript type 'list'".

I was trying to do something similar, but I can't figure out how to subset the average y values to just those in the 400 - 900 x range.

Comment: I will check out that spectra package, thanks for the link!

Comment: I was looking through my answer again and noticed that I had a bracket out of place and I imagine that was probably causing the error. I have fixed it so you might want to try it again. To clarify, the reason you had an invalid subscript type is because that third bracket after the second summary was closing the subscript.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank-you! I also found another variant that also works, using filter: max(filter(summary[[i]], Wavelength >= 400 & Wavelength <= 900)$average)